# Gnuplot: using custom point shapes, with legend entry

Tags: charts, gnuplot, symbols, shapes

Gnuplot provides a number of point styles to use in scatter plots, such as a cross, a star, a square, a circle etc. The available point types can be [demonstrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zojYF.png) by using the `test` command.

However, for a specific application, I need different symbols, and I need legend entries that show these symbols.

In particular, I need more than four symbols that can be plotted both in outlined and in filled state (e. g. triangles pointing left or right, parallelograms or non-square rectangles).

There are a number of approaches to use other shapes (each with some requirements towards the terminal, e. g. unicode support):

- [using PNG images](http://fityk-tutorials.blogspot.de/2010/11/gnuplot-cygwin-and-gnuplot-custom.html)
- using `set label '□' at 3,4` for each point, where □ can be replaced by any unicode character, such as ◁, ▶, ▭, ▮, etc.)
- using `plot ... with labels` and providing a unicode character as a label

The problem with all of these approaches is that I can't get a proper legend (key) entry including the symbol.

I considered plotting the legend myself, but there are two reasons why I don't think that this is feasible:

- For plotting the legend to the right of the chart (or at the lower right inside the chart), I would need to calculate the width of the legend, which depends on the font.
- Some of the plots may include both a line and a points (like `using linespoints` for regular Gnuplot point types), which both have to be shown in the legend.

I am generating the Gnuplot input files programmatically, so an approach that explicitly lists all points (like the `set label` approach mentioned above), or that requires some calcuations, is OK.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This won't be an answer because I'm going to tell you to change your terminal ... I know...

There is no way to add user-defined point shape in gnuplot yet, but the PostScript terminal allows about 70 different : [image: Postscript point types] http://www.cp.cmc.osaka-u.ac.jp/~fumiko/tips/gnuplot_pt.jpg

In the following discussion, they state that there's no general mechanism to add user defined point type. And they come with the solution you gave in your question.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/in57UNxG2o0

I think a way to achieve your objective may be to

1. Use postscript to process a "human-readable" .ps file, using default point types.
2. "post-process" (=parse) the .ps file (it sounds like Inception to me) to change the old fashion ugly default point type into something you like, from unicode chars to home drawn shapes.
3. ps2pdf or ps2somethingyoulike the processed .ps file.

I'm afraid I will have to face the same problem, so let the world know if you find an easier solution :)

Comment: I like the idea, and I will give it a try. I'll have to find a good way to convert the postscript to my target format, though - it's probably easy on Linux, but I need to do it on Windows and I need to produce EMF (for Word) and PDF (for pdfLaTeX).

Comment: Instead of changing the default symbols, you could also define your own symbols and change the symbol invocation (it looks like `3747 2576 CircleF`) to use your own definition.

Comment: Unicode symbols might be a problem, though: I just ran a quick test and it seems that neither IrfanView nor Inkscape render unicode symbols in labels correctly. You could use the Symbol font for greek letters, but I'll need other unicode characters as well.

Comment: I think ps2pdf has its equivalent in windows, and since you're parsing postscript file to add your own content, I think you won't be afraid of using Cygwin if it doesn't :). When it comes to EMF, there is ps2vector to convert ps to emf but it's a commercial software. And ethic should prevent you from using EMF. But I remember embedding directly cropped pages of my pdflatex report into powerpoint presentation (it works fine with office mac, not sure it will help you though)

Comment: In fact, I'd rather not use Cygwin as I want my plotting solution to be reasonably easy to setup for other people. And while I don't like EMF, it seems like Microsoft Word doesn't support svg, pdf, or eps images (when I add an EPS image, it gets rasterized at a rather low resolution).

Comment: I'm not able to help you, but I think you can find someone who may help you on stackexchange somewhere. When you're done with your quest, I think you should write your solution somewhere so that it can be found by the bunch of people facing the same problem.

Comment: I will, assuming a find a satisfactory solution. I might also ditch Gnuplot in favor of matplotlib, although Python is not the language of choice for the project.

Comment: Well, matplotlib sounds sexy. Using Python to produce EMF, I fear that you will end up schizophrenic. Try to keep a connection with Humans ^^

Answer (score 2):

if anyone wants to mess with the postscritp route here is a simple example:

Each symbol is defined by name (See table in Pascali's answer) in the ps file as for example :

```
/BoxF  { 
      ....3 or 4 lines of terse code ...
        } def
```

Replace with your own definition:  This is a capital letter Pi.

```
/BoxF {
 stroke gsave moveto    % required, this finishes prior line and moves to point
0 30 rmoveto  % nudge  symbol to get it centered properly
 /Symbol findfont 120 scalefont setfont (P) Cshow 
 grestore
     } def
```

This simple example may need the numbers (font size) 
tweaked for different types of plots..

If you want to use fonts that aren't known by your postscript interpreter you need to manually include them.

Comment: BoxF is pt 5 by the way.  The numbers are off by one in that chart.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Pascail's answer, you can also do this with SVG instead of Postscript.

SVG is based on XML and may or may not be easier to process than Postscript (using an XML library). It also supports unicode.