# Gnuplot symbols in epslatex terminal with dots inside

Tags: gnuplot

When creating symbols in combination with the epslatex terminal in Gnuplot 4.6, I always notice that in the center of the symbol a small dot is shown (clearly visible on zoom-in). This annoys me quite a bit, as it does not happen in, for example, the png terminal of Gnuplot.

Is there a simple method in Gnuplot to get rid of this dot?

Minimum reproductive example:

```
set terminal epslatex 
set output "test.tex"
test
```

It can be directly observed in the outputfile `test.eps`.

Additional info:
I use the following code to create a complete eps-file out of it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\input{test.tex}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Is there a solution inside gnuplot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16358393/1134387 there are much more symbols than the few shown by `test` in Gnuplot. When using 64, 65 and 66 as `pointtype`, I get symbols without the dot inside, which effectively solves my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since an other question ([Removing dot from centre of empty gnuplot point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54549422/7295599)) has been marked as "duplicate" with no more possibility to answer, I put my answer here to provide some test code and images.

You can do a point test sequence yourself in any terminal.

```
### Terminal test dots
reset session
set colorsequence classic

set terminal postscript color
# set terminal pngcairo
# set terminal pdfcairo
# set terminal qt
# set terminal wxt
set output "TestDot.eps"   # in case of file output set the extension according to terminal

N = 160
M = 10
set parametric
set xrange [-0.5:M-0.5]
set yrange [-M/2:N]
set xtics 1
set ytics M
plot for [i=0:N-1] i%M,floor(i/M)*M w p pt i ps 3 notitle
unset parametric
set output
### end of code
```

**postscript terminal:**

[image]
**pngcairo terminal:**

[image]