# Removing dot from centre of empty gnuplot point

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting data in gnuplot with points. When using point types that I think should be empty dots (as in points with coloured borders but white or clear centres) they still have a small dot in the centre.

An example line is

```
plot sin(x) with points pt 4 ps 5
```

When I open a terminal and run the command `gnuplot` and then run this line, the extra dot does not appear.

When I write the code in a file (plot.gplot) and run it with gnuplot, e.g.

```
set terminal postscript color
set output "image1.eps"
plot sin(x) with points pt 4 ps 5
```

and run the command `gnuplot plot.gplot` then the points appear.[image]

Ubuntu 18.04

gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 2

gnome terminal

Comment: This seems related to the terminal you are using. Have you tried another one (pngcairo for instance)? Are you stuck with Postscript?

Comment: `plot sin(x) with points pt 64 ps 5` should solve your issue. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17040653/7295599

Comment: Thanks @theozh that does work for my situation. I did see that image somewhere else but those point numbers don't line up with what is shown for me -- for example 64 gives a blank square but that image says 64 is a coloured diamond. Is there somewhere else that I can see what extra points I have that aren't listed when you run ```test``` in gnuplot?

Comment: Made an image with the information myself -- [here](https://ibb.co/dk6nMrj)

Comment: You can do a test sequence yourself in any terminal. 
`set terminal postscript color; set output "TestDot.eps"; N = 160; M = 10; set parametric; set xrange [-0.5:M-0.5]; set yrange [-M/2:N]; set xtics 1; set ytics M; plot for [i=0:N-1] i%M,floor(i/M)*M w p pt i ps 3 notitle; unset parametric; set output;`
Since I cannot answer here anymore, I put the code in a more readable form and images here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54568303/7295599