How to plot linepoint in gnuplot such that the lines shouldn't pass through the points and points should be open squares or triangles(not solid)
I want to plot a linepoint plot where I need the line not to pass through the points. When the points are solid, whether the line passes through or not, it doesnot matter. But when the point-types are open, it does not look good.
I have tried with open circle using a trick and it worked. I am sharing the code below.
 set style circle radius 0.007
plot 'data1.dat' u 1:(($3)**2) w l lw 4 lc "blue" notitle,\
'data1.dat' u 1:(($3)**2) with circle fillcolor "cyan" fs solid 0.2 border linecolor "blue" notitle

Now I am trying to use square, triangle and other shapes as point type but I am not sure what command to give for those.
For square, I have tried using the command:
 set size square

 plot 'data1.dat' u 1:2:(0.001):(0.014) with boxxy fillcolor "red" fs solid 1.0 border linecolor "red" notitle

But here trhe problem is the size of the box are not fixed and varies as per range of x and y-axis. It even gets worse when the axis is set to logarithmic scale.
I would appreciate any good solution.

You are probably looking for pointintervalbox, check help pointintervalbox and help pointinterval.
Script:
### linespoint without lines through points
reset session

set samples 11
set pointintervalbox 1.6
set key top left

plot '+' u 1:($1+16) w lp pt 4 ps 2       ti "square", \
      '' u 1:($1+14) w lp pt 6 ps 2       ti "circle", \
      '' u 1:($1+12) w lp pt 8 ps 2       ti "triangle", \
      '' u 1:($1+ 6) w lp pt 4 ps 2 pi -1 ti "square", \
      '' u 1:($1+ 4) w lp pt 6 ps 2 pi -1 ti "circle", \
      '' u 1:($1+ 2) w lp pt 8 ps 2 pi -1 ti "triangle", \
### end of script

Result:


I appreciate your help. I have tried this, and it worked in the terminal. But when I am using the same in Gnuplot eps-latex and then inside the square, a point is shown at the center of the square. This does not happen when I run in a standard terminal. Is there anything that I am missing?

@SrD4443 this, I cannot explain. but different terminals might behave differently and I also have seen dots in the eps-latex terminal. I don't know how to avoid.

I have used point types 64,65,66, which removed the dots inside. The details can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040335/gnuplot-symbols-in-epslatex-terminal-with-dots-inside.

@SrD4443 Good you found it, actually I even gave an answer many years ago. If the above pointintervalbox answer was helpful to your inital question, please upvote and/or accept. If you don't think it answered your question, please add your own answer and accept it (via check mark) for not letting this question appear unsolved. Please also check your earlier gnuplot questions!
